# Integrating a sine function that is to an odd power

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I've started the chapter in my book where we begin to integrate trig functions, so bear in mind I've only got started and that I do not have a handle on more advanced techniques.

$\eqalign{
  & \int {{{\sin }^3}x} dx  \cr 
  &  = \int {\sin x({{\sin }^2}x} )dx  \cr 
  &  = \int {\sin x({1 \over 2}}  - {1 \over 2}\cos 2x)dx  \cr 
  &  = \int {{1 \over 2}\sin x(1 - \cos 2x)dx}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{1 \over 2}\sin x(1 - (2{{\cos }^2}x - 1))dx}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{1 \over 2}\sin x(2 - 2{{\cos }^2}x)dx}   \cr 
  &  = \int {\sin x - {{\cos }^2}} x\sin xdx  \cr 
  & y = {1 \over 3}{\cos ^3}x - \cos x + C \cr} $

---

I got the right answer but it seems like an awfully long winded way of doing things, have I made things harder than they should be with this method?

Comment: http://trevorpythag.co.uk/2009/mathematics/calculus/intergration-using-a-reduction-formula-with-example/

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236543/proving-a-reduction-formula-for-the-antiderivative-of-cosnx

Comment: You could have skipped a bunch of steps: $ \int \sin^3xdx  
   = \int \sin x(1-\cos^2x)dx  $. Then let $u=1-\cos^2x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have unnecessary middle steps, just use $\sin^2x = 1-\cos^2x$ after the second line.

To handle other odd powers:

$$\sin^{2k+1}x=(\sin^{2}x)^k(\sin x)=(1-\cos^2x)^k(\sin x)$$

then use $u=\cos x$.

Comment: I see this now, thank you!

Comment: @Assad:  this works for any odd power of $\sin x$

Comment: @RossMillikan, Could you explain why just odd powers please?

Comment: @Assad Think to $\int\sin^2 x\,dx$, which isn't a polynomial in $\sin x$.

Comment: @Assad:  because you convert an even number of powers of $\sin x$ to $(1-cos^2 x)$, leaving a $\sin x dx $ over to allow the $u$ substitution $u=\cos x, du=-\sin x dx$.  If it is an even power of sine that doesn't work.  There are other ways, a bit harder.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it faster to use subsitution like $\cos(x)=t$?
$$\eqalign{
  & \int {{{\sin }^3}x} dx  \cr 
  &  = \int {\sin x({{\sin }^2}x} )dx  \cr 
  &  =-\int \sin^2(x)d\cos(x)  \cr 
  &  = -\int (1-\cos^2(x)) d\cos(x)   \cr 
  &  = -\int (1-t^2) dt \cr }
 $$

Answer (score 2):

Using the formula $$\sin (3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$$ you can calculate the integral in just one step.