# Reduction formula integral of $\cos^n(x)$

Tags: integration

I need to find the reduction formula for the integral of $\cos^n(x)$.

Ive split it into $\cos(x)\cos^{(n-1)}x$ in the hope of integrating by parts, but I'm unsure how to differentiate $\cos^{(n-1)}$, how should I proceed?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236543/proving-a-reduction-formula-for-the-antiderivative-of-cosnx

Comment: Split into $\cos(x)^2\cos(x)^{n-2}$, then, using $\cos(x)^2=1-\sin(x)^2$, integrate by parts $\sin(x)\sin(x)\cos(x)^{n-2}$, it gives a recurrence relation.

Comment: I'll just try that now - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use the chain rule. The function $f \,:\, x \to (\cos(x))^n$ is the concatenation $g \circ h$ of $g \,:\, x \to x^n$ and $h \,:\, x \to \cos x$, so by the chain rule $$
  f' = (g \circ h)' = (g'\circ h)\cdot h'
$$

Since $g'(x) = nx^{n-1}$ and $h'(x) = -\sin x$, it follows that $$
 \left((\cos x)^n\right)' = -n(\cos x)^{n-1}\sin x \text{.}
$$

Comment: I think I've managed it, but what I've got disagrees with my textbook! I've got the answer to be In=(1/(n-1))sinxcos^(n-1)x+I(n-2)